# Why is 100 used as last parameter in ZF2 while registering events

Tags: php, zend-framework2

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $event->getSharedManager()
          ->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController',
                    'dispatch', 
         function($e) {
              $controller = $e->getTarget();

             //check if logged in, setting up the userid variable of controllers
            if ($e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('AuthService')
                                            ->hasIdentity()) {
                   $users = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()
                            ->get('SanAuth\Model\AuthStorage')->read();

                   $controller->userid = $users['id'];
             }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a priority; the higher the priority value of an event, the earlier it will be triggered in relation to other events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> **attach** attach(string $event, callback $callback, int $priority)
>
> Attaches $callback to the EventManager instance, listening for the
>   event $event. **If a $priority is provided, the listener will be
>   inserted into the internal listener stack using that priority; higher
>   values execute earliest. (Default priority is “1”, and negative
>   priorities are allowed.)**

Read more here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html

Comment: Please can you make me more clear, if i attached 3 events with the last parameter 100 , 200 and -100: then event with 200 will be given more priority then 100 and last for -100. Am i correct.